# Setting a radio button into session to retain checked state

Tags: php, session

I am trying to store the input value of a radio button and storing that intoa session so that if the user roams around the site the radio remains checked unless they switch it themselves and then the new selection remains checked.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="reportSwitch">
    <input checked type="radio" name="reportType" id="leadership" value="1" <?php if($reportType == 1){
        echo 'checked';} ?>>
    <label for="leadership">Leadership</label>
    <input type="radio" name="reportType" id="fundementals" value="2" <?php if($reportType == 2){
        echo 'checked';} ?>>    
    <label for="fundementals">Fundementals</label>
</form>


<?php
$_SESSION['reportType'] = $_POST['reportType'];
$reportType = $_SESSION['reportType'];

if(isset($reportType)){
} else{
    $reportType = 1;
}
?>
```

I cannot seem to to get it to remain in a checked state...

Comment: I think !You should write your php code before html.

Comment: It works BUT when you move to another page it goes back to its original state

Comment: I hope you are not posting any value for `reportType` from another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code

```
<?php
session_start();
$_POST['reportType'] = 1; // for testing it is set define value , you can change 
if(isset($_POST['reportType'])){
 $_SESSION['reportType'] = $_POST['reportType'];
 $reportType = $_SESSION['reportType'];
} else {
 $reportType = $_SESSION['reportType'];
}

 if(!isset($reportType)){
 $reportType = 1;
 }
?>
<form action="" method="POST" id="reportSwitch">
<input checked type="radio" name="reportType" id="leadership" value="1" <?php if($reportType == 1){
    echo 'checked';} ?>>
<label for="leadership">Leadership</label>
<input type="radio" name="reportType" id="fundementals" value="2" <?php if($reportType == 2){
    echo 'checked';} ?>>
<label for="fundementals">Fundementals</label>
 </form>
```

Comment: This does not retain the state

Comment: Hm, that does not keep it checked at all like your previous code example

Comment: It just keeps flicking back to the original the first radio button

Comment: check this my update code , when you refresh this page also session set so it will work

Answer (score 2):

Put the value in session and use the session variable to populate value in radio button in place of using extra variable.

By populating from session It will help to retain in all pages.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['reportType'] = $_POST['reportType'];
?>
<form action="" method="POST" id="reportSwitch">
    <input type="radio" name="reportType" id="leadership" value="1" <?php if($_SESSION['reportType'] == 1){
        echo 'checked';} ?>>
    <label for="leadership">Leadership</label>
    <input type="radio" name="reportType" id="fundementals" value="2" <?php if($_SESSION['reportType'] == 2){
        echo 'checked';} ?>>    
    <label for="fundementals">Fundementals</label>
</form>
```

Comment: That does not keep its state when you move form page to page though?

Comment: on other page in which you not getting value can u do print_r($_SESSION) and see value is there or not....and i hope you not missing session_start()

Comment: fundamentals not fundementals but that works perfectly, far better than the horrible solution I had previously.